# Shadows are extremely dark and the light not working well

Tags: light, unreal-engine5

I am just learning Unreal Engine 5. Building an interior scene from youtube video.
I added sky light and directional light. But the inside looks extremely dark, you can see it in walls. and its different from the video. Looks like light is not working properly. Tried bp_skies, adding post process and adding with env.light mixer. Got the same result, what should i do to get more soft and real shadows and light ?  +rebuild the light, doesnt help (
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VX7F.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqStl.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51rEh.png)

Tried to add different kind of lights, +env.light mixer.
Tried to change intense settings. Did everything like in the video,but got different result (